# Datepicker not cutting off the date properly for 2-digit year format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

jQueryUI datepicker seems to have a bug and it doesn't wrap century as requested. I put 69 as short year cutoff, seems to have no effect. Instead the UI shows 1970 for any year below 87 (so it does not accept them as valid?). Am I doing anything wrong there? Typed value don't get synced to UI when they are between 1970-1986.

[image]

The goal is to allow user to set any dates between 1970 to 2069 with short notation of 70 meaning 1970 and 69 meaning 2069 respectively.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5onew5r8/3/). Stack Overflow's embedded player does not display datepicker's UI properly, it hides the input field - please use jsfiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'm/d/y',
    shortYearCutoff: '69',
    yearRange: '1970:2069'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="myDate" name="myDate" type="date" value="" />
```

Comment: Use the "Full page" version of the snippet to run it here with proper layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `type="text"` rather than `type="date"` in the input field. When you use `type="date"`, the browser controls the formatting of the raw input field, which overrides the datepicker's `dateFormat` option; it doesn't

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'm/d/y',
    shortYearCutoff: '69',
    yearRange: '1970:2069'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="myDate" name="myDate" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the same issue after changing `type="text"`.

Comment: It works for me. If I type `3/31/69` I get March 31 2069. If I type `3/31/70` I get March 31 1970.

Comment: 69 works no problem. It's only for year range 1970-1986, everything becomes 1970 it seems.

Comment: Hmm, looks to me like a datepicker bug. When I change the year, the calendar changes so the days of the week are correct for the new year, but the year in the dropdown doesn't change. And then after I press Enter, I can't get the datepicker to pop up again.

Comment: I see. Well thanks for your answer anyway. I tested under Chrome and having it as `type="date"` doesn't work as intended. After changing to `"text"` it works the same as in Firefox. Do you know a good bug-free alternative to jqueryUI datepicker ?

Comment: You can google "bootstrap datepicker" to find others. But I'll bet they don't have options like `shortYearCutoff`, so it won't actually solve this problem.

Comment: you might also want to post something in the jQuery Forum.

Comment: I found what the issue was. `shortYearCutoff` must be an integer, string value is ignored. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42516977/897326

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** `shortYearCutoff` must be an integer, I put it as a string. jQueryUI datepicker silently ignores it in this case. The following change to my code was necessary to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'm/d/y',
    shortYearCutoff: 69, //integer is important, string will get ignored
    yearRange: '1970:2069'
  });
});
```

[Fixed JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5onew5r8/5/).

Here is the relevant code block in *jQueryUI.js*.

```
_getFormatConfig: function( inst ) {
    //...
    shortYearCutoff = ( typeof shortYearCutoff !== "string" ? shortYearCutoff :
        new Date().getFullYear() % 100 + parseInt( shortYearCutoff, 10 ) );        
    //return ...
},
```

I guess the right way to put it would be checking whether value can be parsed as int, then it would be more inline with Javascript's type-less spirit. Leaving the decision with jQueryUI team.

Comment: Good catch. I'm surprised this is a problem -- if it only makes sense as a number, I'd expect it to convert it internally. Javascript usually takes care of this by itself, but it depends on exactly what it's comparing to.